# Summation sign and factors

Tags: summation

Assuming we have something of this form, where $a_{k}$ is **not** a constant (but $x$ is): $$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}x \cdot a_{k} = a_{k} \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}x$$ Would this be valid? If yes, please provide proof by linking a source. I have not yet found a rule that allows you to put a non-constant factor before the summation sign.

I have noticed that the formal description of my problem is not quite accurate. Let me give an example of what confuses me:

I read : $$2n \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}1$$ and I have not found any rule yet that would justify the $n$ standing before the summation sign.

Comment: But $a_n$ _is_ constant. Did you mean $a_k$?

Comment: @J.G. yes, thanks. I edited that immediately.

Comment: I was implying the $a_n$ should become $a_k$ on the left-hand side of your equation (not the right, though, as its subscript would be undefined).

Comment: _Not the right, though_.

Comment: @J.G. the right should remain as it was before the edit because it is not defined by the summation sign you mean?

Comment: $k$ is a [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples) we sum over, so it can't appear outside the sum.

Comment: @J.G. If I do that my question cannot really be answered anymore. I will give an example  so that what I find questionable becomes clearer.

Comment: I have now again edited the question maybe the thing that confuses me is now clearer.

Comment: However I already understood why the two formulas in my question are problematic so therefore the matter has resolved itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid. The dummy index $k$ does not exist outside of the summation. The right side is meaningless because $k$ is meaningless (in the factor $a_k$).

Remember, the dummy index is only used to indicate that it varies over a range and that the resulting values are summed:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x\cdot a_k \equiv \underbrace{x\cdot a_0 + x\cdot a_1 + \cdots + x\cdot a_n}_{\textrm{no }k\textrm{ appears here}}$$

Note that there is **no $\mathbf k$ on the right side**.

Answer (score 1):

The edited question contains the expression

$$
2n \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}1 
$$

The summation there adds up $n+1$ copies of the number $1$, so the expression is equal to
$$
2n(n+1) 
$$

The meaning of $n$ depends on the context.

You might see an expression like this when trying to think about a loop in a computer program that evaluates an expression that takes time proportional to $n$ and  loops $n+1$ times

Comment: Thanks. Would you agree with this statement: $2 \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}n = 2n \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}1$ ?

Comment: @MathNoob Yes, because the $n$ moved outside the sum going to the right doesn't depend on the bound variable $k$. This is a special case of my answer (but unnecessarily doubled) with $f=n,\,g=1$.

Comment: @J.G. I now see what you mean. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are really three questions here. Yes, $f(n)\sum_{k=0}^ng(k,\,n)$ is legal provided $f(n),\,\sum_{k=0}^ng(k,\,n)$ both exist; we're just multiplying them. (Note $g$ needn't depend on both arguments.) Yes,$$f(n)\sum_{k=0}^ng(k,\,n)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(n)g(k,\,n).$$But no, an $f$ dependent on $k$ can't be moved outside.